# Difference between contraception and abortion?

Tags: morality, abortion, contraception

I'm not sure where I could ask this question so I'm posting here. Sorry if this will create too many answers or a long debate. I just can't find the category where I can ask.

If a parent says to a child I could have contracepted you or aborted you. In both cases the outcome would be the same. The child would never be born.

If God plans something and we decide to prevent it in the middle of the process of 'creation' would that be considered going against Gods will? Isn't then the contraception light version of killing God's will for other human being to live? And from God perspective the same thing as abortion?

Something similar like when someone commits suicide and all his offspring will never come to existence because of this prevention? So 'murdering' himself is also murdering the rest of his offspring.

Comment: VTC until you've got a doctrinal context, Catholicism for one is firmly against contraception, most Protestants are OK with it so you'd have to choose one or the other to get decent answers.  Otherwise one of us is left casting pearls before swine.

Comment: PLEASE TAKE THIS TO CHAT!!!

Comment: Unconstructive comments deleted. If you wish to debate, do so in chat.

Comment: looking for the truth is always unconstructive for the christian community here on stack

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be laboring with a misconception. contraception and abortion are not the same thing;

Contraception loosely defined is the prevention of a pregnancy, while Abortion is the termination of a pregnancy. And while there is some merit to your saying that they both thwart God's plans, you must balance that with the fact that an omniscient God knew that those choices would be made before he created the heavens and the Earth, and also it must be balanced with God not interfering with man's free will.

As far as to the prevention of life, yes it not only prevents one life, but also the lives of their posterity, which is a direct disobedience of God's command in:

> Genesis 1:28  And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth.

From this we see that God had a secondary purpose in creating man which was to have him care for the rest of God' creation, and by putting man into the Garden of Eden;

> Genesis 2:15  And the LORD God took the man, and put him into the garden of Eden to dress it and to keep it.

And even though man seems to be in opposition to God's will at almost every turn the truth is that:

God is all about forgiveness!

> Psalm 103:10 through 12  He hath not dealt with us after our sins; nor rewarded us according to our iniquities. For as the heaven is high above the earth, so great is his mercy toward them that fear him. As far as the east is from the west, so far hath he removed our transgressions from us.

God is never so far away that he cannot hear our prayers of contrition.

Comment: this is much better answer, even though it didn't prove it. Especially abortive contraceptives...but we talk about all preventions...

Comment: @Grasper sometimes things are so evident that proof is unnecessary.

Comment: if we would never care about prove we would still live in the middle age...

Comment: @Grasper What World do you live in where something is not true until proven. Is it necessary to prove that yesterday is gone and cannot be changed. Or that Gravity exists. You apparently believe in the existence of God, but that is probably the most debated concept in History, and if it could be proven by the standard you are setting, there would be no need for faith since His existence would never be a question.

Comment: so why are you talking about something which is evident that proof is unnecessary? Faith won't give you something evident...

Comment: @Grasper Comments is not a chat forum, therefore I will not continue to debate you here.

Answer (score 1):

With these kinds of questions (why is *this* OK and *this* not?) the question is really a matter of the heart. *Why* are you using contraception or *why* are you "using" abortion? God judges our hearts.

> **1 Samuel 16:17b ESV** ...For the Lord sees not as man sees: man looks on the outward appearance, but the Lord looks on the heart.”

One can come up with several non-sinful reasons to use contraception. Perhaps a married couple wants to have sex but they don't want a baby because bring a baby to full term could kill the mother, or they can't afford a baby. The intent of the people there is a wise one, and that's just one example.

Try doing the same thing with abortion. Can you come up with a scenario where one can kill the unborn baby with holy intent? I don't think it exists, and I think that is the answer to your question. One's intent with contraception can be good or bad, but one's intent with abortion is certainly always bad.

Comment: why do you not apply the intention to contraception too the same way as for abortion? Because of the hypocrisy? It's ok to sin in this area but not in this one because it's more visible? It's better to kill someone with a gun then with a knife because with knife there will be more blood?

Answer (score -2):

Contraception is means of preventing pregnancy (like birth control), whereas abortion is killing the fetus while it is within the mother - which by all means would be murder, since the child is living and has a soul.

Again, reiterated, you cannot contracept a child, since contraception is the prevention. Abortion is killing the child within the mother.

It's important to remember that, if God plans something to be, it will be. His will cannot be prevented. You cannot go against God's will. If God wants you to have a child, then no form of prevention could cause otherwise - remember that Mary was a virgin and begot Jesus, and Abraham's wife Sarah was barren and begot Isaac.

Long story short - if the Lord wills it to be, it shall be.

If you commit suicide for the pure reason of preventing offspring, I believe you would answer for both your murder and the preventative murder of your offspring, since that intent would be in your heart.

Comment: this answer is just wrong, sorry. If you can't go against Gods will you have no free will and there is no sin!

Comment: This is not wrong at all. When has anyone ever gone against the Will of God? Never! We have the choice to obey Him and the responsibility to do so, but nowhere in Scripture does it ever say we have the ability to override the very Will of our creator. If every single choice we make is only the result of "free" will, then the Lord couldn't be Sovereign as we know Him to be because He would not have control. Throughout Scripture are examples of people trying to undo the Will of God, only to fail.

We do have our own will - but we CANNOT go against the very Will of God.

Comment: so all evil in this world is His will?

Comment: His will, not necessarily, but he created it - God created EVERYTHING - it was Adam and Eve eating the fruit from the tree that made evil known to us, not created it. In Isaiah 45:7, the Lord himself says "I form the light, and create darkness: I make peace, and create evil: I the LORD do all these things."

Comment: -1 for the reasons Grasper says, and also for stating as fact an opinion not held by all Christians.

Comment: I never stated anything for a fact. I took Scripture (the Word of God) to show that while it may not be His will, he did create evil. But this is going off the subject. Grasper asked for the difference between contraception and abortion, which I answered both by definition and the simple fact that if God will's it to be, it will be. Unless you can somehow argue God's omnipotence.

Comment: @Jesse you seem to be negating the fact that God did not create man in his fallen state, and that that imperfection is the cause of all melee. God's omnipotence was never intended to overcome man's free will. That is the purpose of forgiveness.

Comment: I understand God did not create man in his fallen state. But the fact remains - you cannot undo the Lord's will. By what standards is it the purpose of forgiveness? Adam and Eve had free will before there was sin, and they did not need to seek forgiveness at that time. This implies God only gave us free will after sin, which is false. God's omnipotence is above all, because God is above all. If God wills something to be, He need only say "be". If God wanted you to be a frog, you would become a frog - whether you wanted to or not.